# How to use environment variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I am beginner in using batch files.

I have added `visstudio` system variable with value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

So `echo %visstudio%` will give me the path of Visual Studio in cmd.

Now how could I use this variable so that I can run application from my batch files? I need this as I have multiple projects and I don't want to move in folders.

```
@echo off
start %visstudio% "%cd%\Src\Edge\Test\Edge.Test.sln"
```

Earlier I used to do like:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "%cd%\Src\Edge\Test\Edge.Test.sln"
```

If I update Visual Studio then I again need to change the VS paths in all batch files, and that nobody will like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start "window name - can be empty but not omitted" "%visstudio%" "%cd%\Src\Edge\Test\Edge.Test.sln"
```

`start` interprets the first "quoted parameter" as a window title. It can be empty.

The executable needs to be in quotes since it contains spaces.